# Regular expression and file_get_contents

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I use file_get_contents PHP function to load DEMO1 website data.

In DEMO1 HTML source code I see example this code:

```
<div class="sample"></div>
  </div>
              <div class="desc desc3">
    <ul class="FLT">
                  <li>
          <p class="orange">NIK:</p>
          815000244            </li>
                        </ul>
    <div class="fl"></div>
  </div>      
            </div>
<div class="43332"><p /></div> </div> <li><p class="numbers">Tep</p>876 654 832</li>
```

What regular expressions use, to select only 815000244 and 876 654 832 numbers (using 2 different RE)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = file_get_contents('DEMO1.html');
preg_match(',NIK:</p>\s*(\d*),', $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[1], "\n";
preg_match(',Tep</p>([\d\s]*),', $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[1], "\n";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.